# Getting Date a Year From Now in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a spreadsheet in Google Drive to keep track of when we need to get our employees their annual reviews. As part of the calculations, I need to be able to compute their anniversary dates by adding years to their start dates. I'm trying this:

`returnDate = returnDate.setYear( returnDate.getYear() + 1);`

Alas, the scripting language that google supports seems to lack many of the useful functions of a fully-fledged Javascript Date object, as I get this error on that line when I try to run it:

`TypeError: Cannot find function setYear in object 1357106400000. (line 28, file "Code")`

So, how can one compute a series of anniversary dates using the tools available in Google Apps Script?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works like this :

```
function addOneYear(y){
  var fullYear = y.getFullYear();
  return new Date(y.setFullYear(fullYear+1));
}
```

According to Javascript specifications [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) getYear and setYear are not recommended

Comment: Welp, I thought I'd tried that, but I'd apparently gotten bits of the syntax wrong or something. Working like a charm; thank you, sir.